# Running Buffer.from on base64 string returning Uint8Array instead of Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64, buffer

I need to get an image in the form of `Buffer` like in the example below:
[image]

But when I run `Buffer.from` on a `base64` string I'm getting `Uint8Array` like in the example below:
[image]

```js
const originalUrl =
      'https://i.picsum.photos/id/621/200/300.jpg?hmac=GgxwZqdPsVQwlM2QhfHoLU8gZ7uo_PP6oD4KmIq-ino';
const response = await axios.get(originalUrl, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

const base64Str = response.data.base64Slice();

// returns Uint8Array
const brfFromBase64String = Buffer.from(base64Str, 'base64');
```

How can I turn a `base64` string into a `Buffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the the `Uint8Array`,`strBuffer`, into an `ArrayBuffer` with `.buffer`. Then pass it to `Buffer.from` to get `Buffer`:

```
const buffer = Buffer.from(strBuffer.buffer);
```